# How to decrease array nesting

Tags: php, arrays

Basically my array is nested too deep. It has three sub,sub,sub arrays and I only want to keep the middle one.

I find it hard to explain it but what I have is this:

```
"data": [
  {
  "order": 
      {
        "id": "1,", 
        "mail": {
        "mail1": "X";
        "mail2": "X";
         },
      },
      {
        "id": "2,", 
        "amount": "X", 
      },
   }
 ],
 "data": [
   {
  "order": {
        "id": "3,", 
        "amount": "X", 
      },
    }
 ],
```

I need to remove the first and last sub-arrays so I only get only one nest:

```
     [1] {
        "id": "1@hotmail.com,", 
        "mail1": "X", 
        "mail2": "X", 
      },
     [2] {
        "id": "2,", 
        "amount": "X", 
      },
     [3] {
        "id": "3,", 
        "amount": "X", 
      },
```

I don't know if this make sense. I'm sure this is not very difficult to do, but I only managed to make a foreach that creates an array with all values, but I lose all sub arrays.

How is this done? (at least removing the first array).

Comment: That array structure seems incorrect. Either it's nested incorrectly or you have two `order` keys in the same array, which is not possible. Please provide an accurate example.

Comment: @Liso22: No, you did not. Your array is still incorrect. Please be precise and provide correct array you wanted to process and correct array expected as a result. Using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on your real arrays would be more helpful than providing incorrect JSONs.

Comment: @Liso22: show us where your array, ex: `$array = array('data'=>array('order'=>array('id'=>'1@hotmail.com,','mail'=>'mail')));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array structure is still invalid so I can't say for sure, but something along these lines should do:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array['data'] as $order) {
    $order = $order['order'];
    if (isset($order['mail'])) {
        $order = array_merge($order, $order['mail']);
        unset($order['mail']);
    }
    $result[] = $order;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$finalArr = array();
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
  array_push($finalArr, $val);
}
print_r($finalArr);
```

Hope it helps